# Python: SerialException: Attempting to use a port that is not open

Tags: python, serial-port, xbee

I am using below python code to communicate with XBee+Arduino from my MAC+XBee coordinator. But I am getting port not open error while trying to send the packet through serial.

Error message

```
Sending LOAD
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xbeeTxRx.py", line 139, in <module>
    main()
  File "xbeeTxRx.py", line 109, in main
    sendPacket(WHERE, LOADString)
  File "xbeeTxRx.py", line 49, in sendPacket
    data = what)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xbee/base.py", line 399, in send
    self._write(self._build_command(cmd, **kwargs))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xbee/base.py", line 91, in _write
    self.serial.write(frame)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 517, in write
    raise portNotOpenError
serial.serialutil.SerialException: Attempting to use a port that is not open
```

Code below. The problem happens as soon as I add the def main. If there is no def main and I call the sendPacket(WHERE, LOADString) then it works fine.

```
#this port address will change
PORT = '/dev/tty.usbserial-A104IC2U'            
BAUD_RATE = 9600


WHERE = '\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\xF7\x43\xC1'


UNKNOWN = '\xff\xfe' # This is the 'I don't know' 16 bit address
dataString='LOAD'
LOADString='LOAD:T1name=-60.00&T2name=-40.00&T3name=-20.00&T4name=0.00&T5name=+20.00&T6name=+60.00'
STOPString='STOP'

packets = Queue.Queue()

# Open serial port
ser = serial.Serial(PORT, BAUD_RATE) 

def message_received(data):
        packets.put(data, block=False)
        print 'gotta packet'

def sendPacket(where, what):
        zb.send('tx',
                dest_addr_long = where,
                dest_addr = UNKNOWN,
                data = what)
        print 'Sent Packet'

def sendQueryPacket():
        sendPacket(WHERE, dataString)
        print 'Sent Query Packet'   

def handlePacket(data):
        print 'In handlePacket: ',
        print data['id'],
        if data['id'] == 'tx_status':
                print data['deliver_status'].encode('hex')
        elif data['id'] == 'rx':
                print data 
                print repr(data['source_addr_long'])
                print data['rf_data']
        elif data['id'] == 'rx_long_addr':
                print data 
                print repr(data['source_addr_long'])
                print data['rf_data']
        else:
                print 'Unimplemented frame type'



# Create XBee library API object, which spawns a new thread
zb = ZigBee(ser, callback=message_received)

def main():
        print ("Sending LOAD")
        #send load command
        sendPacket(WHERE, LOADString)
        while True:
                try:
                        time.sleep(0.1)
                        if packets.qsize() > 0:
                                print 'packet availabe'
                                newPacket = packets.get_nowait()
                                handlePacket(newPacket)
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                        print("Sending STOP")
                        sendPacket(WHERE, STOPString)
                        break

zb.halt()
ser.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude you should put `zb.halt()` and `see.close()` after the last if statement where you call your main.